# How to open quicktab tab from external page (after clicking link url)

Tags: navigation, blocks

i have a slider with link field at my front page, and quicktab section on another page. The slides and the quicktabs are connected, so i want when i click on the link at the slider to open the specific tab. The quick tabs in my case use class active for the clicked section to show. How can i make the tab active externally with click on the link at the slider?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to patch it yourself as the [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/308633) here is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

right click with mouse on the Quicktab in question, and copy url. Then use that url on your slider.